# Touch functionality on scrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uiscrollview

I am working on an app where my task is to get url-links from the database that i created a scroll view and placed images on the scroll. 
I have written some code that when i click on the image i have to show the url page in a webview which i placed above the scroll view. 
 For this i wrote touch code for getting the url when i click on the image but i got problem like my click is not working on the image and scrollview also but it is working on the down part of the image and scrollview which is a normalview. U can find my touch code below

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];   
    for(int index=0;index<[array count];index++)
{

    UIImageView *imgView = [array objectAtIndex:index];  
      if(CGRectContainsPoint([imgView frame], [touch locationInView:scrollView]))
        {  
            NSString *strgetcontenturl = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[arrayvideoFile objectAtIndex:index]];  
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strgetcontenturl];  
            [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strgetcontenturl]]];
            NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];  
             [webview loadRequest:requestObj];

        }}}
```

Here **array** is where i stored all the images init and **arrayvideoFile** is where I stored all the urls.

Please help.

Comment: how you have added images on scrollview?

Answer (score 0):

How did you placed your images to your scollview? ImageView?

I would place them with a UIButton (CustomType), then you can add target to that button and no need to detect touches. Because an UIButton already detects the touch events.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton butttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage * buttonImage = ....
[button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonAction:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[scrollview addSubview:button];
```

Edit: Added code

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am getting images from database i tried to give the image to the button background but it didn't worked

Comment: please find the changes in the question i just discovered it now @mert

Answer (score 0):

just set `imgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;` it may help you.

otherwise use this code

```
UIScrollView *scrollview4preview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-44)];
    scrollview4preview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview4preview];

    int yval=0;
    for (int i=0; i<[arrary count]; i++) {
        UIButton *btn4preview=[[UIButton alloc]init];
        btn4preview.tag=i;
        btn4preview.frame=CGRectMake(scrollview4preview.frame.origin.x+10, i*yval, 150, 150);
        [btn4preview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn4preview addTarget:self action:@selector(btnPreviewSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btn4preview.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
        [scrollview4preview addSubview:btn4preview];

    }

    scrollview4preview.contentSize=CGSizeMake(scrollview4preview.frame.size.width, yval+160);


-(void)btnPreviewSelect:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

NSString *strgetcontenturl = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[arrary objectAtIndex:btn.tag]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strgetcontenturl];
[webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strgetcontenturl]]];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Comment: [btn4preview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImageName.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];here can i place my array in which i stores all the images that are coming from db, because i have more than one images

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
for(int Tag =0; Tag < [array count]; Tag++) {
    UIButton *btn_URL = [UIButton butttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIImage * btn_URL = [btn_URL setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btn_URL.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

    [btn_URL addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    btn_URL.tag = Tag;

    [scrollview addSubview:btn_URL];
}

-(void)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:[sender Tag]]]];

}
```

Here you can redirect user to URL.

If you need any help then let me know.

Thanks,

Hemang.

Comment: can i paste this code between touch code or where i declared images

Comment: No.... Don't use touch method. Paste for loop where do you want to add button having image in scrollview and then below method to detect action.